# How to Insert/draw Image/text inside canvas circle in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, flutter-layout

I want to draw/insert image and text inside canvas circle but I am unable to do that. I am posting screenshot for better understanding of my requirements

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqGGu.png)

**Code**

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(buildContext).size;
    double strokeWidth = 10;
    Rect myRect = Offset(-size.width * 0.21, -40) &
        Size(size.width * 0.195, size.width * 0.195);

    var paint1 = Paint()
      ..color = Color(0xFF23BBFF)
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    var paint2 = Paint()
      ..color = Color(0xFFFF8623)
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    double firstLineRadianStart = 0;
    double _unAnswered = 0.30;
    double firstLineRadianEnd = (360 * _unAnswered) * pi / 180;
    canvas.drawArc(
        myRect, firstLineRadianStart, firstLineRadianEnd, false, paint1);

    double _learned = 1 - _unAnswered;
    double secondLineRadianEnd = getRadians(_learned);
    canvas.drawArc(
        myRect, firstLineRadianEnd, secondLineRadianEnd, false, paint2);
  }

  double getRadians(double value) {
    return (360 * value) * pi / 180;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
```

Comment: Can you provide your code snippet?

Comment: use Stack widget

Comment: @p2kr already used stack but it relocates canvas circle

Comment: @quoci I only had UI and design that screens. I had created circle but dont know how to insert image inside canvas circle

Comment: use it with Align widget